# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadCurrentSession')

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I use shopify api, why I get this error message:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadCurrentSession')
```

```
 const Shopify =  require('@shopify/shopify-api');

 const { Product } = require('@shopify/shopify-api/dist/rest-resources/2022-04/index.js');


// Initializing a client to return content in the store's primary language

  const test_session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(request, response);
  const d = await Product.all({
    session: test_session
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Define this function in your root server.js file

```
 export default async function returnSessionData(req, res) {
  const decode =  await Shopify.Utils?.loadCurrentSession(req, res);
  return decode
}
```

And Call this returnSessionData(req, res) from your route-controller

Comment: Please, would you elaborate on this answer? Adding the calling code would be helpful for extra context. Also, why is this the default export from server.js?

Comment: That will return undefined